# Allow decimal value to Selection.Find.Font.Position

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I'm coding a win word c# application to create footnotes automatically based on non superscript yet ' font position = raised' words. I have set find font position as bellow to capture raised text.

```
wordApp.Selection.Find.Font.Position = 3;`
```

But in actual word document there are many raised characters with raised by 3.5 pt (With decimal point). Bellow is the macro code I recorded in word document for searching 3.5 pt.

```
Sub Macro6()
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Font.Position = 3.5
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute 
End Sub
```

Yet in c# interop `wordApp.Selection.Find.Font.Position` is a int parameter so I cannot set 3.5 as font position, Can someone advice on this how to search text with decimal raised font positions.

Comment: According to the VBA documentation, the `Position` property is a `Long`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193398.aspx so I'm not surprised that the interop API has it as an integer-valued property. Very annoying, though!

Answer (score 0):

If you have code that converts raised numbers like those you mention to footnotes in word documents and are willing to share it. That would be really useful for me.

I regularly work with pdf versions of research documents that have many footnotes and converting them to word documents with footnotes actually recognized as footnotes would be useful for many reasons.

I've only been able to find the macro available here:

http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f57/pdf-to-word-footnotes-474419.html